# favicons not displaying in quasar project

Tags: vue.js, favicon, quasar-framework

In my current project, I am struggling with getting the favicons to show up.  I updated my `index.template.html` to reflect the icons:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="statics/cu.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="statics/icons/cu-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="statics/icons/cu-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="statics/icons/cu-96x96.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/ico" href="statics/icons/favicon.ico">
```

I checked that the `quasar.conf.js` file had an updated pwa:

```
icons: [{
                    src: 'statics/icons/cu-16x16.png',
                    sizes: '16x16',
                    type: 'image/png'
                },
                {
                    src: 'statics/icons/cu-32x32.png',
                    sizes: '32x32',
                    type: 'image/png'
                },
                {
                    src: 'statics/icons/cu-96x96.png',
                    sizes: '96x96',
                    type: 'image/png'
                },

                ]
```

I confirmed that they do exist in the correct directory.  However, when I run it locally I always get a 404 error on the icons.  Any advice and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-webpack/developing-spa/app-icons-spa

Let icon genie CLI do it for you.